# Hide a column in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

How can I hide a column or make it narrower to be able to see more of the file name? The file names are often much longer than will fit into the "Name" column.

[image: Google Drive]

Comment: its not possible, you can only change either the view to tiles, or change density from comfortable, cosy or compact

Comment: How much of the screen are you using? I have one file name with 32 chars for example and it appears in the list in full using Firefox.

Comment: I never maximize windows since I like to keep two windows/apps visible next to the other. File names are often 50 characters and they don't fit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, but may help.

You could use your browser's zoom function (e.g. hold down the control key and spin the mouse wheel) to see more in each column. If the text gets too small, you can use a screen magnifier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to use the search facility to narrow down the file names so that, hopefully, you will not need to see the entire file name to find what you want.